# What should I do about the maximum file size for AWS lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

I am trying to host a YouTube downloader consisting of a NodeJS app using YTDL so it can be accessed at my school, I am creating a site with a bunch of tools for media creation in class. I have basically just copy pasted the entire thing because I know nothing about NodeJS. So I had it working locally as an express server and then I needed to figure out how to open the server that got the video files .

I tried to use LocalTunnel first and that worked well but because I would have to change the LocalTunnel url each time it wasn't really an option.

Then I saw that lambda would be a good idea so a I spent a few hours randomly pressing buttons on the AWS console and managed to get it to work. Except AWS Lambda has a max invocation payload of 6MB which once I upped the length of the video above a few seconds it hit the maximum.

Im at a bit of a loss of what to do now. Port forwarding on my router never seems to work and I would rather host it externally anyway. I have read somewhere that I could upload it to S3 first but that seems a bit too much for what im trying to do.

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

//app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello world!'))



app.get('/', (req,res) => {

   var URL = req.query.URL;
   console.log("downloading: " + URL);
   res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"');
   ytdl(URL, {
       format: 'mp4'
    }).pipe(res);

});
module.exports = app;
```

This is the code that's on my lambda function if that helps.

Comment: Can you stream the video in chunks smaller than 6MB? Or 'save' the result to an s3 bucket instead of returning it as the response for the request? Have a read of https://seancoates.com/blogs/lambda-payload-size-workaround/ maybe his solution is usable for you. I feel like aws lamba is not really meant to do the heavy lifting in video related apps.

Comment: You may want to try Heroku - it's free plan has no maximum response size and a very high bandwidth limit (2TB).

Comment: Be aware of the YouTube terms of service that state "... is intended for real-time viewing and not intended to be downloaded (either permanently or temporarily), copied, stored, or redistributed by the user."

Comment: Or you could use: [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein in what way is youtube-dl different? Would it solve my problem?